# Make a voice call with Agora Kit

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, agora.io

I'm using [AgoraKit](https://www.agora.io/en/) to build a voice call app 'VOIP' long side with CallKit.

When I'm trying to put the same **channelId** on 2 different devices and make join to channel, everything is going well.

What I want to do is to make the first device call the second one by defining a UID, So the second device will ring when ever the first one called it.

The problem is that I can't define a specific id for the device to call it, I looked up on Google for all the tutorials about joining a call with callKit even the code samples on Agora didn't help.

In another word, I'm trying to make the same logic as Messenger app, when ever the user call another user it should be going to ring.

Any idea would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Are you using any database to store user information?

Comment: @Aqeel yes I'm using firebase database

Comment: have you implemented VoIP ??

Comment: @Aqeel Yes man I did implement Agora with callKit

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH30
have you implemented this push kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function inside of the VoIP where you can find a unique device id. On the bases of this id you can make a call to other person.

```
 // Handle updated push credentials
    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
        // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server
    }
```

this is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH30)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try, thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you, that what I was missing @Aqeel

Comment: @AqeelAhmad and @AbdHayek how did you initiate the call? Presumably you would need to define a `channelId` so both the receiver an caller can ` agoraKit.joinChannel`.  But then you'd have to communicate this channelId to the receiver right? You would have to use callkit and push kit together? But how do you send that push notification carrying the channelId and maybe the callerID?  Are you guys using pinpont from aws?

Comment: @xiaolingxiao I'm working on php server side, so it handles the notification requests